# C - Allocating dynamic memory for integer and using it

Tags: c, memory-management

i am trying to allocate memory for integer but i get a warning **assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast** and when i do a cast for an int i get a warning **cast from pointer to integer of different size**

here is my code for first :

```
int i;
for(i = 0 ; i < gNumOfAllFiles ; i++)
{
    int *v=(int *)malloc(1*sizeof(int));
    v=0;
    dependencies[i].visited =(int)v;
}
```

or

```
dependencies[i].visited =v
```

The **dependencies[i]** is a struct contains field **int visited** and i am trying to initilize it by 0

Comment: Writting to a pointer: `*v = 0`. Reading from a pointer: `visited = *v`.

Comment: Why are you trying to assign a pointer-to-int to an int? What's your intent?

Comment: Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)!

Comment: This code will leak memory: if `gNumOfAllFiles` is 1000, you'll allocate 1000 ints, but never free them. For each `malloc` call, there has to be a `free` to match it

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong because it tries to cast the pointer address as an integer:

```
dependencies[i].visited =(int)v;
```

Do this instead (to get the contents pointed at by v):

```
dependencies[i].visited =*v;
```

edit: also, to set the contents of the pointer
use 
     *v=0; instead of v=0;

Answer (score 1):

`v` contains the address of a piece of memory.
`(int)v` casts this address to an integer, which is a mostly-meaningless operation.

You want to get the value that occupies the memory at this address, using the *dereference operator*:

```
int value = *v;
```

Similarly, `v = 0` makes your pointer point to memory address `0` (which is NULL), and leaks the memory you allocated using `malloc()`.

You can store a value in the memory pointed to by the pointer using the dereference operator:

```
*v = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `dependencies[i].visited =*v;`

Comment: `dependencies[i].visited =*v;` isn't exactly a good idea right after he assigns `v = 0`...